# JS multiple class same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I use js to load big image whent hover to list thumbnail ok. but don't work to multiple.

How to: hover `.thumbs .item` of `boximg_01` or `boximg_02` .... loading only image in `boximg_1` or `boximg_02` width one js function. multiple `boximg_*` loading img only of element.

Now when hover `thumbs img` of `boximg_01` it run 2 big img on both `boximg_01` & `boximg_02`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box-image .thumbs img").hover(function() {
    var imgpath = $(this).attr("dir");
    $(".box-image .image").html("<img src=" + imgpath + ">");
  });
});
```

```css
#image {
  max-width: 348px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
#thumbs, .thumbs {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}
.thumbs .item {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boximg_01 box-image">
  <div id="image" class="image">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400">
      </a>
    </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
      <div class="item active"><img dir="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100"></div>
      <div class="item"><img dir="https://picsum.photos/id/2/400/400" src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boximg_02 box-image">
  <div id="image" class="image">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/400/400">
      </a>
    </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
      <div class="item active"><img dir="https://picsum.photos/id/3/400/400" src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/100/100"></div>
      <div class="item"><img dir="https://picsum.photos/id/4/400/400" src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/100/100"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `$(this)` and DOM navigation methods to refer to elements in the same DIV.

Comment: @Barmar can you help me a example run code snippet. JS not a my strength...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOM navigation relative to `this` to find the related image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box-image .thumbs img").hover(function() {
    var imgpath = $(this).attr("dir");
    $(this).closest(".box-image").find(".image").html("<img src=" + imgpath + ">");
  });
});
```

```css
#image {
  max-width: 348px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
#thumbs, .thumbs {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}
.thumbs .item {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boximg_01 box-image">
  <div id="image" class="image">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400">
      </a>
    </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
      <div class="item active"><img dir="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100"></div>
      <div class="item"><img dir="https://picsum.photos/id/2/400/400" src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boximg_02 box-image">
  <div id="image" class="image">
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/400/400">
      </a>
    </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
      <div class="item active"><img dir="https://picsum.photos/id/3/400/400" src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/100/100"></div>
      <div class="item"><img dir="https://picsum.photos/id/4/400/400" src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/100/100"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, better use `.empty().append($("<img>", {src: imgpath}))` instead of `.html` to be safe against XSS if the filepath is dynamic.

Comment: I would really use `.find(".image img").attr("src", imgpath")`

Comment: Oh, right, the `img` element already exists - and also that wouldn't destroy the `fancybox gallery` wrapper.